# Position of Max value in ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there any efficient way of finding the position of the maximum value in an ArrayList? I have written the following code and would like to know if it is possible to make line 2 in code below more efficient.

```
static int getPatternCount(ArrayList<Integer> indicesInPool, int indexofEndStr) {
        int position = indicesInPool.indexOf(Collections.max(indicesInPool));
        return (Math.abs(indexofEndStr - indicesInPool.get(position)) + 1);
    }
```

Comment: Looks pretty good. You could try asking on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: each time you add to the ArrayList you evaluate the value and create a variable highest.

Comment: Can I ask why you want the position of the max value? There may be another data structure that could better suit your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The second line will end up iterating the list twice.

You can get better performance by writing a loop (by hand) that looks for the largest value AND tracks the position that it occurs at.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = ...
int limit = list.size();
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int maxPos = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    int value = list.get(i);
    if (value > max) {
        max = value;
        maxPos = i;
    }
}
// maxpos now contains the (first) index of the largest value ...
// ... or -1 if the list is empty.
```

There may be a 3rd-party library that offers this as a library method.

---

I don't think there is a faster way to do this with one thread.  If the list was really large, using multiple threads to scan different sections of the list might give you better performance.  However, you'd have the complications / overheads of synchronization and setup.  And the actual performance is likely to be limited by the hardware memory system; i.e. size of caches and memory bandwidth.

---

Depending on how the list is used, you may be able to track the largest value and its position more efficiently in other ways.

- If you only add elements at the end of the list, and never update or remove elements, then you can update a variable containing the largest element and its position each time you `append` and element to the list.
- In the more general case, it *might* be possible to design and implement a specialised custom list type to track the maximum and maximum position in the face of any kind of update.  But the data structure would be complicated and memory hungry, and operations like `get` would go from `O(1)` to `O(logN)` or worse.